# Maximized MDI child is restored when a new child is created

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mdi

I have a current active MDI child window that is "Maximized", but upon creating a new MDI child window, the current active MDI's state was changed to "Restored". Is there a way that the current active MDI will remain "Maximized", and the new MDI is in restored state?

Based from articles I read, if one is MDI child is maximized, all the other child windows will be maximized as well (same with restored, and minimized). Is this true? Are there workarounds?

Comment: It seems [a documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-mdicreate#remarks). But I cannot reproduce the maximizing the newly activated child window behavior.

Comment: I'm also confused by that, it says to maximize the newly activated child but the created child was also in restored state.